# how do i click a <div> button using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a button visible on UI as "Add New" using Selenium Webdriver in Python 2.7 but when using id or class name there is error "Unable to locate element".

```
add_new_btn = driver.find_element_by_id("buttonAddEditEntryId")  
add_new_btn.click()
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="buttonAddEditEntryId"]
```

Below is the html code  :

```
<div id="buttonAddEditEntryId" class="k-button" title="Add New Record">
                        <i style="font-size:14px; padding:5px" class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true">
                        </i>Add New
                    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try setting any kind of a wait?

Comment: No. I am new in this...started learning testerday itself. I was able to click login and navigate but cant click buttons

Comment: Also it immediately thows unable to find error...even if i choose to click in diffrent line of code.

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3124333

Comment: Really appriciate that... :)

Comment: @SiKing as you know i am a beginner...could you recommend any good tutorial that can help me learn how to find xpath and all ? I got css selectors and class but xpath is killing me.

Comment: I learned the basics from this: http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html After that, just Google whatever you need.